# Load gltf model from contents, not URL

Tags: vue.js, three.js, google-drive-api

I am currently downloading a gltf from Google drive using the Google Drive API. I can print in the console the gltf file as text but I can't seem to be able to parse it and actually visualize it in three.js. I have used GLTFLoader.parse and GLTFLoader.load but both give errors about the json. Is there a workflow for reading files from their content without loading them from a URL?

the response I am getting back from google-drive looks like that:

**response body image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a workflow for reading files from their content without loading them from a URL?

Yes. The idea is to directly call the `parse()` method with the respective content. The [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) is using this approach during file import. The normal approach for this is:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.parse( contents, '', ( gltf ) => {

    const model = gltf.scene;
    scene.add( model );

} );
```

`contents` can be of type `string` or `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mugen87, I have already tried what you propose but the parser keeps giving JSON errors as the gltf content contains both string and binary segments. What do I do about that?

Comment: Can you request the glTF model from the Google Drive API as type `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: I think that is what I am doing.  No?
  
`this.$gapi.request({
          path: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1WG0MXAVj8YD2eO9fep5YPNftyZlkQzE',
          method: 'GET',
          params: {
            alt:'media'
          },
          //mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
          responseType: 'ArrayBuffer'
        }).then(this.seeResponse);
`

Comment: Okay, strange. Are you able to reproduce the issue with a live example (like a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?